# Do you need trash bins in queue lines?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I know you need trash bins around your park to prevent it from becoming a garbage dump, but do you need trash bins in queue lines? Or does the sim behavior of littering or puking stop when in line?

Comment: Good question. I don't have a canonical answer, but I've never put trash bins in my queue lines and I've never seen trash dropped in there (although people will get sick in line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sims refuse to litter queue lines. However, they will use trash bins placed in queue lines, and if the trash bins are kept empty, nearby sims will receive a green thought about how clean the nearby area looks. Puking still happens in queue lines regardless of trash bins, requiring a janitor to patrol the queue lines every so often.

NB: For some reason, the Park Inspector *does not* check trash bins placed in queue lines, so you *can* receive "clean park" rewards despite the trash bins in your queuess looking like a set pieces for the movie Wall-E.

Comment: Perfect! Also, do you know if they use benches in queue lines, or if the queue TV monitor path extra does anything at all?